# Searching exact phrase in Lucene

Tags: mysql, database, search, lucene

I have a single table of 10 GB in MySQL. The table consists of data about the suppliers, products and contracts. I am indexing the data using Lucene and to make the search faster. I have many conditions on which I filter my data like Supplier name, product name or contract Number or combination of any two.

The issue is Example: When I am searching for Products by entering the supplier name.  Let the supplier name be "Company of Clothes". What I am getting is a list of products supplied by "Company of Clothes", "Company of Shoes","Company of bags" and not only the products supplied by the "Company of Clothes". How can I make Lucene search for only the exact word/phrase I entered.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the QueryParser to construct your queries.  You may find it helpful to give a read to the [query syntax documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_2_1/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Overview).

---

You can use a phrase query, by surrounding your query with double quotes:

```
"Company of Clothes"
```

Comment: Can I use Multi field query and phrase query together using boolean query.